# Jquery Mobile Button Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, blackberry-webworks

I've included Jquery & Jquery mobiles latest versions.

I'm  basically trying to use a mobile button to call a JavaScript function but having issues.

This works fine in chrome but not in webworks on the playbook (this is where i get the errors)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/personSearch.js" ></script>
```

Including my custom JavaScript code

Within that file i have the folllowing code

```
    function testme()
{
    alert("tet");
}
```

I've tried all the following ways:

```
<input type="button" onclick="testme();" value="Button" />
<a id="psClear" href="javascript:testme();" data-role="button" data-inline="true">Clear</a>
```

For them all I get the error:
mainMenu.html:1ReferenceError: Can't find variable: testme

I think its something to do with the way J query Mobile renders buttons but not sure...

UPDATE

If i add rel="external" to the page before it loads in the javascript and works fine, but reloads all the scripts again, and doesnt work without rel="exnteral"

```
    <link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jqueryMobileCSS.css">
    <link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/customStyle.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqueryMobile.js"></script>
    <script src="js/eBar.js"></script>
    <script src="js/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ain.js"></script>
    <script src="js/tleBar.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ps.js" ></script>
```

So without rel="external" js/ps.js doesnt seem to load...
The scripts located on both pages are the exact same but the new page has js/ps,js loaded in aswell..
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use **inline** Javascript ([read why here](http://css.dzone.com/news/why-inline-css-and-javascript-)) to call functions. It looks like the error you're having is related to the fact that your `personSearch.js` file hasn't loaded and therefore the function may not exist exist. Use the Chrome/Firebug JS console to check whether the function is definitely **defined** and then create another script with something resembling the following inside:

```
$(document).bind('pageinit',function () {
    $("#psClear").on('click',function(){
      testme();
     });
});
```

This will make sure that the DOM is loaded and ready before binding the click event to your button. Make sure this script is loaded **after** your `personSearch.js` script.

Comment: Thanks, updated question with more detail could you explain the issue?

Comment: Have you tried it in an external file rather than calling the function from the onclick attribute yet?

Comment: Yes, That works but the problem seems to be when i go in to my page if i do the libk to the page to include rel="external" it works but without that it doesnt

Comment: If you don't use rel='external' does the script load at all? Can you update your question showing the ordering of your script loading as well please?

Comment: This isn't the issue, but it's best to be consistent with your attributes inside your script tags, don't specify a type in some, but not others.

Which script is the `testme()` function in and which script is the click event for the `#psClear` button in?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13987/discussion-between-dan-prince-and-liam-mccann)

Comment: Do not use `$(document).ready`.
it will not work for jquery mobile.
You're should use `$(document).bind('pageinit')`
Refer to docs. 
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/api/events.html